# Constraints on eigenvalues due to the form (symmetry) of Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-groups, symmetry

So I have to deal with a square matrix with complex elements $A$ given by - 
$$A_{ij}(k) = \underbrace{\frac{1}{2}(c_{ij}+c_ji)}_{\text{symmetric under interchange of $i$ and $j$}} \exp(Ik(i-j))$$
Where $I=\sqrt{-1}$
Notice that the matrix is Hermitian iff $k$ is real. 
The only **symmetry** i could meaningfully obtain constraints on the eigenvalue was -
$$A_{ji}(Re(k),-Im(k)) =  \left(A_{ij}(Re(k),Im(k))\right)^* $$

$$\implies A_{ij}(Re(k),Im(k)) =  \left(A_{ji}(Re(k),-Im(k))\right)^* $$

$$\implies \sum_{ij}U^\dagger_{ai} A_{ij}(Re(k),Im(k)) V_{jb} = \sum_{ij}U^\dagger_{ai} \left(A_{ji}(Re(k),-Im(k))\right)^*  V_{jb}$$

$$RHS = \left(\sum_{ij} V^\dagger_{bj} A_{ji}(Re(k),-Im(k)) U_{ia}\right)^*  $$
$$\therefore \text{complex eigenvalues } a_n(Re(k),-Im(k)) = \left(a_n(Re(k),Im(k))\right)^* \implies a_n(k^*) =  \left(a_n(k)\right)^*$$

Thus -
$$ Re(a_n(k^*)) =  Re(a_n(k)) $$
$$ Im(a_n(k^*)) = -Im(a_n(k)) $$

This is all I have till now. It would be nice if someone could prove some of the following observations I have made by plotting the values over a grid of k, with the constraint $Im(a_n(k)) = 0$.
While here the eigenvalues appear to be a complex function $a_n$ of a complex variable, if we manage to invert them such that we could talk of a multivalued function $k(a_0)$ given that $a_0\in \mathbb{R}$ -

1. $\forall a_0\in \mathbb{R}$ there are exactly N $k_0 = $, where N is the dimension of the square matrix $A$.
2. there are are saddle points at $k=\pm 2\pi$ and at $k=0$.

Note that these observations might not be generally true for such matrices - only for special cases!

Comment: I think your question would read a lot more clearly if you altered it so that the expression $\exp(ik(i - j))$ occurring in the first line used different symbols for the index $i$ and the $i$ which is $\sqrt {-1}$; or am I missing something?

Comment: A typesetting oddity: the code \underbrace{...}_\textrm{symmetric under interchange of $i$ and $j$} had $i$ and $j$ appearing without italics, so I changed \textrm{} to \text{} and then $i$ and $j$ did not appear at all.  So then I tried \underbrace{...}_{\textrm{symmetric under interchange of $i$ and $j$}}, with braces around the whole subscript, and it worked.